# Memoization Libraries for C?

Tags: c, memoization

For a project I'm working on, there are a number of states where calculations can be relied upon to return the same results (and have no side effects).  The obvious solution would be to use memoization for all the costly functions.

I would need to have memoization that handles more than one state (so that I could invalidate one cache set without invalidating another).  Does anybody know a good C library for this sort of thing?  (Note that it can't be C++, we're talking C.)

I've worked with some good implementations in Python that use decorators to be able to flexibly memoize a bunch of different functions.  I'm kind of wondering is there's a generic library that could do similar things with C (though probably with explicit function wrapping rather than convenient syntax).  I just think it would be silly to have to add caching to each function individually when it's a common enough issue there must be some off-the-shelf solutions for it.

The characteristics I would look for are the following:

1. Can cache functions with various types of input and output
2. Manages multiple different caches (so you can have short-term and long term caching)
3. Has good functions for invalidating caches
4. Intended to be used by wrapping functions, rather than altering existing functions

Anybody know a C implementation that can handle all or most of these requisites?

Comment: It is not clear to me how such a thing would work. A memoizing wrapper like `memoize(void*func, void*returnVal, int return size, ...)`? Seems complicated and fragile. A pile of preprocessor hackery? You *can* do amazing things with that kind of stuff, but it also tends to be fragile and can become a maintenance nightmare. But, in any case, good question.

Comment: It would be much nicer in C++11 with perfect forwarding, but I could imagine it done in C with some perf loss by providing a dictionary of type descriptors to `memoize()`. About as fragile as printf().

Comment: Memoize by the bit pattern of the data.

Comment: So nobody has actually seen a library that supports this?  That's pretty amazing, given the massive amount of C code out there.

Comment: @Namey: People do memoization all the time in C, but a generic C library – "generic" in terms of how C++ has templates or how Python decorators wrap this – is painful and fraught with pitfalls.

Comment: @Fred: I guess I see it differently.  Is it less painful and fraught with pitfalls to have to re-invent the wheel every time one wants to memoize an individual function?  I'd rather have one painful thing to maintain in one place than 1000 ad-hoc implementations scattered everywhere in the code.

Comment: With that said, I do acknowledge the much higher difficulty level of a "generalizable" C approach.  Unlike python, there is no generalized equality operator for checking arguments, etc.  This means a portable memoize function might only handle by-value args and be totally unable to evaluate the contents of data pointers.  But that would still be something pretty useful.

Comment: @Namey: I meant "painful and fraught with pitfalls" for *each use* of that library. As far as when writing, adding "internal" memoization (using knowledge of the implementation) is *very* simple compared to writing a generic library. The cost of repetition is less than the cost of alternatives, IMHO.

Comment: @Fred: I guess we'll just have to agree to disagree.  I tend to think about programming as an exercise in transforming and passing information, where you want to use the DRY principle liberally.  From that standpoint, I'm not sure why using a library would be much more difficult than writing a new set of memoization aparatus each time.  With that said, I'm not proposing that anyone write such a library- I'm asking if anyone has SEEN one.  At that point, I could test drive it and see if it is indeed painful enough to want to make my own wheels from scratch.

Comment: With that said, if someone says "Hey, I just wrote a C library for this after seeing your question" and it works, I would definitely consider it as a valid answer. ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, seeing as there were no memoization libraries for C and I was looking for a drop-in solution for memoizing existing C functions in a code base, I made my own little memoization library that I'm releasing under the APL 2.0.  Hopefully people will find this useful and it won't crash and burn on other compilers.  If it does have issues, message me here and I'll look into it whenever I have the time (which would probably be measured in increments of months).

This library is not built for speed, but it works and has been tested to make sure it is fairly straightforward to use and doesn't display any memory leaks in my testing.  Fundamentally, this lets me add memoization to functions similar to the decorator pattern that I'm used to in Python.

The library is currently on SourceForge as the [C-Memo Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c-memo/).  It comes with a little user manual and a couple of 3rd party permissively licensed libraries for generic hashing.  If the location changes, I'll try to update this link.  I found this helpful in working on my project, hopefully others will find it useful for their projects.

Comment: I used your library and it works! Quite well. I wrote pretty much the exact same program in python, it ran in 2m 50s native, while 7s in pypy. The C program ran in 46s.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  I've made a couple of cleanups so it will work happily with more compilers.  Also, that's an impressive time for PyPy.  They must be doing some interesting things under the hood for optimization.

Comment: Yeah, well PyPy has been in development for many years by a team of PhDs... so I'm guessing they use some pretty hardcore maths.

The program I wrote was written to solve some Project Euler problem, though it's been so long and I've forgotten which one.

Comment: Yah, I know.  It's still pretty impressive to get a 25x speedup over the original Python, however.  I had recalled the usual speedups over cPython being more on the order of 2-5x.

Answer (score 1):

[memoization](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Memoization) is all but built into the haskell language. You can [call this functionality from c](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Calling_Haskell_from_C)

Update:
I'm still learning about functional programming, but I do know that memoization is fairly common in functional programming becuase the language features make it easy. I'm learning f#. I don't know haskell, but it is the only functional language I know of that will interact with c. You might be able to find another functional programming language that interfaces with c in a more suitable fashion than what haskell provides.

Comment: Certainly an interesting comment.  It seems a bit like overkill to start wrapping C in Haskell, however.  I'd also worry about the potential performance hit from extra Haskell-generated C code that isn't really needed.  There would also be the problem that I am unclear how this approach would help memoize functions implemented in C.

Comment: I updated my answer with a little more detail. Its not too helpful, and I wouldn't have provided this answer at all if it weren't for the fact that your question has been here for 2 days without an answer. If it ends up a dead end for you, I'm sorry and wish you luck. However if it does work out, then I'm glad to have helped.

Comment: Hey, thanks for trying at least.  An outside-the-box answer is still at least a stab at it.

Answer (score 0):

Why, just can't be C++?

Just for a starting point look to this memoization function:

declaration:

```
template<typename T, typename F>
auto Memoize(T key, F function) {
  static T memory_key = key;
  static auto memory = function(memory_key);
  if (memory_key != key) {
    memory_key = key;
    memory = function(memory_key);
  }

  return memory;
}
```

Usage example:

```
auto index = Memoize(value, IndexByLetter);
```